# sum of square errors in proc iml

Tags: sas, newtons-method, sas-iml

I'm trying to create a code to run Newton Raphson optimization. I'm using proc iml, but when I need to evaluate the error (e) I need to sum up all the square differences and don't know how to tell SAS that in that case I need the sum of the components of the vector and not the vector.
The code is the following:

```
proc iml;  use chap0; read all var{X} into X; 
            read all var{t} into t; 

W=1;           
s= exp(X*w)/(1+ exp(X*w)); print s;
e = (s - t) ** 2; /*here I need the result of the sum for that and not the matrix*/
g=2*(s-t)*s*(1-s);
h=2 * s * (1 - s) * (s * (1 - s) + (s - t) * (1 - 2 * s));

count=0;/*init count number*/


do until (e<1e-8); 

 count=count+1; 
 w=w0-g/h;   /*here I also need the sum of g and h*/
 s= exp(X*w)/(1+ exp(X*w));  
 e = (s - t) ** 2;  
 wo=w;  
end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [SSQ](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect257.htm) function to calculate sum of squares in IML.

```
e=ssq(s-t);
```

Here are several other ways to do this.  Note the first way gives a different result (as it's summing the squares of s and -t), just an example of the difference of how you pass the arguments.

```
proc iml;
 x = 1:5;
 y = j(1,5,2);
 e1=ssq(x,-y);     *sum of the squares, not actually subtracting note, so it is not the same answer;
 e2=ssq(x-y);      *sum of squares of the differences;
 e3=(x-y)*(x-y)`;  *multiplying a vector by its transpose sums it;
 e4=(x-y)[##];     *summation subscript operator, see note;
 print e1 e2 e3 e4;
quit;
```

Rick Wicklin has a [post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/05/23/compute-statistics-for-each-row-by-using-subscript-operators/) about the ## operator, which is quite useful.